# Clustering related areas with k-means in WEKA

Tags: clustering, data-mining, text-mining, k-means, weka

I am trying to cluster related areas of knowledge. A sample of my file is:

```
'Domain Ontology,Semantic Web'
'Linked Data,Domain Ontology,Use Case'
'Domain Ontology,Linked Data,Semantic Annotation'
'GIS,Open GIS,Integrated Geo Systems'
'Open GIS,GIS'
```

My file contains 48963 rows and 19000 areas. I have tried grouping words (like in the sample), using StringToWordVector (STWV), but I don't have good results. So I tried different K for my cluster since 3 until 13000. When K is greater my log likelihood decrease. In many models my words are grouped perfectly, but the percentages are not really good for some clusters. For example for K=3000, the 2999 have between 0,1% and 1% of the data, but the 3000 have the 21%. I am using WEKA. Anyone know some work related, some advice or any help is helpful...

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

k-means won't work for this task.

In fact I believe none of the algorthms will **without gigabyes of data describing "common knowledge"**.

Much of the semantic web is motivated by the observation that **you cannot understand text, without background knowledge of how concepts relate to each other**. And since then, they've been trying hard to build larger and larger data bases of structured "common sense" knowledge...

Comment: Yes, You're right. But based in publications I want to cluster all the keywords. I don't have a meaning of the words, but at least I'm clustering words that are related based on his own words of different papers and I could say this set of words belong to AI or Semantic Web or so on!!